# Why does my computer crash when I make a linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list

Hello I am a beginner c++ programmer who has been thinking about linked list. I came up with the following code, but when I ran it my computer crashed. I am wondering exactly what causes my computer to do this.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct list
{
    int value;
    list* nextlist;
};
list* getnewstruct (list* phead, int nextvalue);
void printarray (list* phead);
int main()
{
    int nextvalue = 0;
    list* phead = NULL;
    while (nextvalue < 5) {
        phead = getnewstruct (phead, nextvalue);
    }
    printarray (phead);
}
list* getnewstruct (list* phead, int nextvalue)
{
    list* newlist = new list;
    newlist->value = nextvalue;
    newlist->nextlist = phead;
    return newlist;
}
void printarray (list* phead)
{
    while (phead->nextlist != NULL) {
        cout<<phead->value<<endl;
        printarray (phead->nextlist);
    }
}
```

Comment: in main, nextvalue is never updated.

Comment: You need to work this out on an operating system that has isolated processes so that it doesn't crash your entire computer.

Comment: nextvalue is always 0 so always < 5 so it will loop until you run out of memory, then bad_alloc but could freeze up your computer due to it being low in memory in the interim

Comment: Aside from the problem with the never-changing `nextValue`, your `printarray` needs to decide whether it should recurse or iterate.

Comment: Your computer is crashing because you are not using a *debugger* to step through your code.  You may want to change your mindset from "it compiled, it worked" to "it compiled, it must be debugged."

Comment: @ThomasMatthews - sadly, we are the debuggers.  It's really hard work and you have to make notes and think about stuff and analyse stuff.  Better just to write code and then get some other sucker to debug it:(

Answer (score 1):

Your program simply runs "forever" because you are not incrementing `nextvalue` which leads the `while (nextvalue < 5)` to run at every iteration.